# How to get the character distances in a string in GDI+

Tags: c, gdi+

I am trying to port some of my code from Linux to Windows. In this code I need to draw text on a 32bit ARGB bitmap, using colors with transparency.

The usual GDI functions don't preserve the alpha channel and simply cut transparent holes in my bitmaps. So, I was forced to use GDI+ (the flat API) instead and it work fine with ARGB colors.

But now I need to determine the distances between the characters in a string, using GDI+ fonts.

Or in short, something like GetCharacterPlacement or GetTextExtentExPoint but to work with GDI+ graphics and fonts objects.

How to implement this functionality?

Comment: Did you try MeasureCharacterRanges: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.measurecharacterranges.aspx

Comment: Well, maybe. The description is a little bit vague. And it is not clear how to handle the object arguments in plain C.

Comment: Oh I didn't notice your tag is C.